# How does `:nth-last-child` work when CSS is cascading in nature?

Tags: css, dom, css-selectors, w3c, css-cascade

I've learnt CSS like below statement:

> It only can go further *or* deeper in `DOM`.

And that's the reason we don't have a previous selector like we do for next selector ( `selector + nextLM` ) or we don't have a parent selector because we can't go backwards in DOM tree as *CSS engine*'s point of view.

So there should be two different questions here. If we accept the above explanation, I can't understand how can `:nth-last-child()` work. It's basically going backwards in DOM tree as it starts at the end of an element.

And if we don't accept our introduction, then why don't we have a **previous element** selector?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Imagine it like a counter. When you scan the dom tree you keep track of the number of elemets so later you can easily identify them by indexes either using `nth-child()` or `nth-last-child()`. Technically you aren't going backwards.

Comment: @TemaniAfif hmmm, so am I right? It scans the whole `DOM` at first place, then start to traverse from top to bottom. I mean, browser CSS engine is doing this when we open a website. and when we `.append()` another element, browser does the process again from the beginning?

Comment: well, I don't know exactly how everything is done behind the scene but what I know is that the concept of a previous selector would require a lot of computing than a simple `nth-last-child()` where you only need indexes of element. Too bad that our CSS selector expert is no more active to give you a detailed explanation

Comment: @TemaniAfif I really appreciate the information you already have provided

Comment: No time to compose a proper answer but basically "because of performances". There is [this issue](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2731) explaining why it matters. Even though there is an `:has()` selector being defined it's still per this "perfs" argument that it's [marked as At Risk](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#w3c_process_revision) and still not implemented anywhere... :nth-last-child is not that complex, all it takes is to grab all the children and walk it from the end, but even this [requires optimization](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=461878).